# Approximating a floating point number with correct rounding off

Tags: shell-script, floating-point

How can I approximate a floating point number using shell-script (say, up to 4 digits after the decimal point)? I have two examples:

`A=1.2345678` and `B=1.2345678E-05`.

So I would like to get `A=1.2346` and `B=1.2346E-05`.

I can do a quick job for `A` by using `cut` :

```
A=`echo $A | cut -c1-6`
```

But that gives me `A=1.2345` where I was expecting the last digit round-off to be `6` (since the next digit is greater than 5). Also it does only work for one digit before the decimal point (what if I want to approximate `100.2345678` ?) Same goes for `B` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
$ printf "%.4f\n" "$A"
1.2346
$ printf "%.4f\n" "$B"
0.0000
$ printf "%.4e\n" "$B"
1.2346e-05
$ printf "%.14f\n" "$B"
0.00001234567800
$ printf "%.4g\n" "$B"
1.235e-05
$ printf "%.4g\n" "$A"
1.235
```

Since `%e` might change the exponent, to be sure of keeping it the same, you can use the shell's [string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) features to separate the number from the exponent and print each separately:

```
$ B=100.12345678E-05  
$ printf '%.5fE%s\n' "${B%E*}" "${B##*E}"
100.12346E-05
```

The `${B%E*}` prints everything up to the 1st `E` and `${B##*E}` is everything after the first `E`.

Comment: for the second one you may want to use `printf "%.4e\n"` to keep the exponent.

Comment: +1 or use `%.4g` for both and let `printf` apply the default rule for whether to use the `e` format

Comment: @steeldriver Nice, didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Thanks a lot.  :) It works for most of the purposes. Only trouble I get when I have something like `B=100.2345678E-05`. Then `printf "%.4g\n" "$B"` yields `0.001002` and  `printf "%.4e\n" "$B"` produces `1.0023e-03`. So the exponent value changes, which I may not desire to happen. :(

Comment: @hbaromega what would you want to see?

Comment: I want to keep the power in the exponent unaltered, i.e. `100.2346E-05`.

Comment: @hbaromega you might have to parse it then: `printf '%.4fE%s\n' "${B%E*}" "${B##*E}"`, I don't know if it's possible in another way.

Comment: @terdon Thanks, I have edited your answer and included that. If you want, you may add some explanations.